# Android Studio AlertDialog edges

Tags: android, android-studio, styles, android-alertdialog, edges

[can you see the white edges?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXxbE.jpg)

These edges are driving me crazy!
Does anyone knows how to eliminate them?
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Use this : dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);